# Ways to call an activity other than searching for Package

Tags: java, android

What i mean by that, i have a voice commanded app. Whenever user says something the input is stored in a string and then i check the string for keywords. If i catch the word "camera", i instructed the phone to open the camera like this:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.android.app.camera");
if (launchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```

There is a problem however, since this package name corresponds to a Samsung app, this will only work on Samsung phones. I need a way to call for apps other than their specific package. Maybe call them by name? i don't know if that is even possible but i am dry on ideas.

EDIT: The camera was just an example. I don't want to code specifically for each app. I just want the device to search and open any app matching certain keywords that i use.

Comment: Have you tried: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskCaptureIntent

Comment: I don't want to code for the camera, i just want to use the existing camera app as i already do, but i don't think this will work on phones other than Samsung phones because i call the app with a package name and phones by other manufacturers will have different camera apps, or calendar apps etc with different package names than the ones i use.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I linked `Take a photo with a camera app` from the developer guides.